# How do i extract numbers only from a list of string and create a columns in dataframe based on output?

Tags: python, pandas, list, split, calculated-columns

I have a list of strings, given below
from which i want to extract only numbers, and then i want to create a column based on output.

```
['CGST- INPUT 9%  MAHARASHTRA',
 'SGST-INPUT 9%  MAHARASHTRA',
 'CGST INPUT @6% MAHARASHTRA',
 'SGST INPUT @6% MAHARASHTRA',
 'CGST- INPUT 2.50%  MAHARASHTRA',
 'SGST-INPUT 2.50%  MAHARASHTRA',
 'TDS ON OFFICE RENT',
 'TDS ON CONTRACTOR',
 'TDS ON CONSULTANTS',
 'TDS ON OFFICE RENT (COMPANY)',
 'TDS ON CONSULTANY FEE']
```

Output should be as belows

```
Rate    CGST      SGST     TDS
 9       XX        XX      XX
 6       XX        XX      XX
2.50     XX        XX      XX
```

I have few columns in a Dataframe which i have converted to list above.
There are values in each column which i want to sum and show them saperatly as per the rate mentioned in each list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression that will identify numbers in a string (including those with decimal fractions) is:

```
r'[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+'
```

So, for example :

```
import re
mystring = 'abc50def6.75ghi'
pattern = r'[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+'
print(list(map(float, re.findall(pattern, mystring))))
```

**Output:**

```
[50.0, 6.75]
```

Having extracted your numbers you can then use these values to build your Dataframe

Comment: It's true, you're right